# numberic as object key, value as array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with this object?

```js
const ob= {
  "1": [
    {
      "name": "destination"
   }
  ]
}, {
  "2": [
    {
      "name": "destination"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why can't I do `ob['1']` or `ob['2']`? object's value can't contain array?

Comment: The problem with the object is that its syntax is invalid.

Comment: either an array bracket is missing, or you have a closing and opening curly bracket, in the middle, too much.

Answer (score 2):

Your object structure is incorrect. You need to put `1` and `2` on the same level of object `ob`:

```js
const ob = {
  "1": [{
    "name": "destination"
  }],

  "2": [{
    "name": "destination"
  }]
};
console.log(ob['1']);
console.log(ob['2']);
```

Comment: so it's indentation issue?

Comment: @Hanz - No, look again. You were terminating the object too early. Ankit fixed that.

Comment: wow didn't see that!

Comment: @Hanz you can always copy paste your object in browser console to check the correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your object is invalid. The closing brackets are messed up.

```js
const ob = {
  "1": [{
    "name": "destination",

  }],
  "2": [{
    "name": "destination",

  }]
}

console.log(ob['1']);
console.log(ob['2']);
```